# build two build xml files using a single ant script

Tags: xml, ant, build

I have two build xml files in different folders.
I need to write an ant script that will build both these files sequentially.

Currently, my script is:

```
<import file = "path1"/>
<import file = "path2"/>
```

Only the file specified in the first path is running and not the other.

Thank you

Comment: How do you know that it is only working for the first and not for the second? What happens if you change the order of `import` statement?

Comment: If I reverse the order, only the file specified in path2 is getting built

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to look at the [subant](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/subant.html) task

If you have a base `build.xml` like this:

```
<project basedir="." default="build" name="document.unit-test">
    <target name="build">
        <subant target="build">
            <fileset dir="." includes="*/build.xml"/>
        </subant>
    </target>
</project>
```

You could then create sub build folders like `A/build.xml` and `b/build.xml`

**Build A** `A/build.xml`

```
<project basedir="." default="build" name="project.a">
    <target name="build">
        <echo message="building A"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

**Build B** `B/build.xml`

```
<project basedir="." default="build" name="project.b">
    <target name="build">
        <echo message="build B"/>
    </target>
</project>
```